# Mongodb - Create object as value during aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have documents such as:

```
{
  "city": "New York",
  "name": "Foo",
  "geo": {
    "lng": 123456,
    "lat": 123456
  }
}
```

I am grouping them by city. I would like to get average geo location when I group all objects inside that city.

`geo` property is structured this way to follow [Geospatial Indexes and Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) convention. 
I want output from aggregation to keep this format.

This is how my query looks like:

The `geo` part is wrong even by syntax. I tried to use `$push` method but it created array with multiple values but instead I want to keep same format, just calculate average coordinates for objects per city.

```
db.filtered_hotel_data.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$city",
      "geo": {
        "$avg": "$geo.lng",
        "$avg": "$geo.lat"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id":0,
      "geo":1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.filtered_hotel_data.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$city",
        lat: {
          $avg: "$geo.lat"
        },
        lng: {
          $avg: "$geo.lng"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        geo: {
          lat: "$lat",
          lng: "$lng"
        }
      }
    }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to push then unwind your arrays :

```
db.filtered_hotel_data([
  {$group:{
     _id: "$city",
     city: "$city",
     name: "$name",
     "lng": {$avg: "$geo.lng"},
     "lat": {$avg: "$geo.lat"}
   }
  },
  {$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    name: "$name",
    city: "$city",
    geo: {$push: {
       lat: "$lat",
       lng: "$lng"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {$unwind: "$geo"},
  {$project: {
     _id: 0,
     geo: 1,
     name: 1,
     city: 1
  }}
])
```